# Disconnecting a keg

Tags: beer, keg, gas

I have a mobile bar business and wanted to add draught beers to our menu.  I am a layman with regards to this but I understand how the basic system works using a CO2 (or 70/30 CO2 & Nitrogen) and a beer cooler.

My question is about how long the opened kegs will last seeing as I will need to disconnect them for travel and store them unrefridgerated.  Will they last until the next event?  Also will the gas be easy to disconnect and use again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of kegs do you use and how long is it typically between events?

Answer (score 5):

As long as you aren't using air purged cask type "kegs" you'll be fine.
Disconnecting a keg from the hook up seals the keg from the outside air, and contains the pressure already applied.
Assuming you're using the proper pressure to dispense, the beer's carbonation level will remain the same.

If the beer is unfiltered, or has been naturally carbonated, there will be yeast sediment in the keg.  Moving those kegs and serving too soon will result in hazy beer.

Lastly, some say that shaking a keg will create foam.  And once that foam has formed it reduces the capacity of the beer to make more foam.  I.E. Beer has a limited amount of foam positive compounds present, and when they are gone they are gone.  Not likely a big deal with the first few moves, but if the keg isn't getting finished quickly you might noticed diminished head formation.